# output json object from python to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

(new to python) I am writing a very simple python function, outputting json for my javascript to get.

when I run the python script on command line, it output json object

```
print json.dumps(data)
```

on the js,

```
    this.$http.get(link_to_python_script).then(function(response){
        console.log('data',response.data);
    }, function(error){
        console.log('http error',error.statusText);
    });
```

when I examine the response on browser it has this header:

```
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

and in browser console.log prints out the entire python script instead of json object.
I would like to keep everything very simple and not using extra addons. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: please share more of your python code. generally, maybe using `print` isn't right, but some http server library, like at least https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html or so. `print` writes usually to STDOUT, which is probably not where HTTP responses are getting written to

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, but `json.dumps` does not _output a json object_. It outputs a string. Cf [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps). Rather, you want to use `json.dump()`. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump)

Comment: what do I need to change in the python script for the javascript to pick up as a proper application/json object? i use 'return json.dump(data) ' the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time, I ended up using Flask or the python Open() function to read and write the file. As Faboolous said, print is not the right way.